# flutter_stripe is not showing keyboard on android

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am using `flutter_stripe` plugin for stripe payment. It is working on IOS but on android i am getting this error when i open payment screen.

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.app.ss:layout/card_input_widget: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

Card payment is simple screen from example of flutter_stripe

```
Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  child: CardField(
                    onCardChanged: (card) {
                      setState(() {
                        _card = card;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  child: LoadingButton(
                    onPressed: _card?.complete == true ? _handlePayPress : null,
                    text: 'Pay',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

here is my MainActivity.kt

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
}
```

and i am using     `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0'` in build.gradle

Comment: Have you taken a look at the thread here (https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/142)?

Comment: yes but when i use the styles.xml file my app crashed and unable to create build

Comment: Have you solved the issue? just facing the same...

Comment: When ran in iOS simulator it worked fine, but in an actual android device i got an empty field.  No hint of Cardnumber or MM/YY or CVV.  Theme.AppCompact or its decendants is the key.

Comment: Is this still an issue we recently improved the experience on this